# Using Python and tkinter, what benefit is there to using __init__ when creating a Frame in a class?

Tags: python, tkinter, frame, init

I am learning Python and tkinter by going through several tutorials (python-course.eu & effbot.org).  I have come across a pair of situations and am trying to learn the reasons behind the differences.

NOTE: I found many questions regarding `__init__` in class, but not `__init__` in frame.

Both call a class from the main, and use a constructor (`def __init__`) to create an instance of the class.  Am I using correct terminology?

They both create a frame; however, one uses `Frame.__init__(self,parent):` and the other uses `Frame(master):`

- Why does the first include `__init__` in the construction of the frame?
- Why does the second omit 'self' in the arguments when creating the frame?
- Why does the first not use 'pack' to place, but the second does?
- What other differences are noteworthy?

The following are MWE to produce the respective outputs.

```
import tkinter as tk

class Checkbar(tk.Frame):
   def __init__(self, parent=None, picks=[], side=tk.LEFT, anchor=tk.W):
      tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
      self.vars = []
      for pick in picks:
         var = tk.IntVar()
         chk = tk.Checkbutton(self, text=pick, variable=var)
         chk.pack(side=side, anchor=anchor, expand=tk.YES)
         self.vars.append(var)
   def state(self):
      return map((lambda var: var.get()), self.vars)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   root = tk.Tk()

   lng = Checkbar(root, ['Python', 'Ruby', 'Perl', 'C++'])
   tgl = Checkbar(root, ['English','German'])
   lng.pack(side=tk.TOP,  fill=tk.X)
   tgl.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
   lng.config(relief=tk.GROOVE, bd=2)

   def allstates(): 
      print(list(lng.state()), list(tgl.state()))
   tk.Button(root, text='Quit', command=root.destroy).pack(side=tk.RIGHT)
   tk.Button(root, text='Peek', command=allstates).pack(side=tk.RIGHT)

   root.mainloop()
   print("You've selected ", list(lng.state()))
```

[Language Widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLUs4.png)

```
import tkinter as tk

class App:
    def __init__(self, master):  

        frame = tk.Frame(master)
        frame.pack()

        self.button = tk.Button(frame, text="Quit", fg="red", command=master.destroy, padx=20)
        self.button.pack(side='left', expand=10)

        self.hi_there = tk.Button(frame, text="Hello", command=self.say_hi)
        self.hi_there.pack(side='left')

    def say_hi(self):
        print("Hi there, everyone!")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = App(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

[Hello Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4uCzR.png)

Thank you, kindly.

Comment: The former is a subclass of `tk.Frame` while the latter is not. Therefore, `Checkbar` is and can be used as a tk.frame, while the latter, `App`, isn’t and can’t.

Comment: What you're seeing is the difference between two approaches to object-oriented programming: inheritance (a CheckBar *is a* Frame) vs. composition (an App *contains a* Frame).  A CheckBar doesn't pack itself, any more than a plain Frame packs itself: that's the responsibility of the user.  In fact, it couldn't pack itself in the example you gave: there are two instances of this class, that are packed differently, how would it know which set of parameters to use?

Comment: @jasonharper: you should move your comment to the answer section.

Comment: All of the questions you're asking can be answered by reading a little documentation or working through a basic python tutorial. Almost none of this has anything to do with tkinter.